# systemctl output is truncated

Tags: systemd

A need to grep the output for this command:

```
systemctl | grep failed
```

The problem is that it does not show complete units:

```
systemd-...-clean.service loaded failed failed        Cleanup of Temporary Directories
systemd-...-setup.service loaded failed failed        Recreate Volatile Files and Directories
tcsd.service              loaded failed failed        LSB: Init script for TCSD
cups.socket               loaded failed failed        CUPS Printing Service Sockets
```

Your can see the units show like: `systemd-...es-clean.timer`
for `systemd-tmpfiles-clean.service`

I tried with a file:

```
systemctl --failed > file
```

Or cat:

```
systemctl --failed | cat
```

But the problem is the same. 
I need to understand why that happens and how fix it.

Comment: Just for the future, `man systemctl` or `man somethingelse` solves most of these problems ;)

Answer (score 6):

This is not related to pipes, is `systemctl`'s behavior. Use the `--full` switch to get full names:

> ```
> --full
>     Do not ellipsize unit names and truncate unit descriptions in the
>     output of list-units and list-jobs.
> ```

Answer (score 0):

pipe it to less first and then try your grep:
`#systemctl status -l httpd | less | grep failed`